# How can I assign result.insertId to id from function that i pass in query() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

When i try to log id variable i get 'undefined'. How can I assign result.insertId to id from function that i pass in query() function?

```
var id;
connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', {title: 'test'}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(result.insertId);
  id = result.insertId;
});
console.log(id);
```

Comment: Try to log `result` instead, perhaps you simply have the wrong property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to log `id` before it's value is set in the `query` callback.

Look at the comments below:

```
var id;
//this will execute immediately
connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', {title: 'test'}, function(err, result) {
    //this executes after the query returns
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(result.insertId);
    id = result.insertId;
}); 
//this will execute next, BEFORE the query result is available
console.log(id);
```